# WPF и Entity Framework: как вывести информацию из связанной many-to-many таблицы в Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, many-to-many

Пытаюсь прибиндить к столбцу  информацию из связанных many-to-many двух таблиц. 
Есть два класса по учету мобильных устройств и их IMEI: CDevice и ImeiList.

```
public partial class CDevice
{
    public CDevice()
    {
        this.ImeiList = new HashSet<ImeiList>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ImeiList> ImeiList { get; set; }
}

public partial class ImeiList
{
    public ImeiList()
    {
        this.CDevice = new HashSet<CDevice>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long IMEI { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CDevice> CDevice { get; set; }
}
```

Во ViewModel есть коллекция:

```
private static ObservableCollection<CDevice> _oCollDevice;
public static ObservableCollection<CDevice> OCollDevice
{
    get
    {
        if (_oCollDevice == null)
            _oCollDevice = new ObservableCollection<CDevice>();
        return _oCollDevice;
    }
}
```

А также два метода, один из которых получает сведения из базы данных:

```
public static List<CDevice> GetDeviceList()
{
    using (DevicesEntities context = new DevicesEntities())
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        var deviceList = context.CDeviceSet.
            Include("ImeiList").ToList();
        return deviceList;
    }
}
```

А второй его вызывает и добавляет полученный список в коллекцию:

```
private void GetDevices()
{
    var CdeviceResult = GetDeviceList();
    OCollDevice.Clear();
    foreach (var item in CdeviceResult)
    {
       OCollDevice.Add(CurrentDevice);
    }
}
```

С ViewModel через Datacontext связано View, в котором есть Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OCollDevice}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Наименование (производитель)" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Модель" Binding="{Binding Path=Model}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IMEI" Binding="{Binding Path=ImeiList.IMEI, Mode=OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Вопрос: как вывести в данную таблицу информацию, чтобы отображались все IMEI и соответствующие им устройства, и чтобы отображались все устройства и соответствующие им IMEI. Сейчас в столбце "IMEI" пусто, хотя коллекция учитывает количество совпадающих IMEI и через PROFILER виден LEFT OUTER JOIN, который выводит нужную информацию. Как вытянуть в таблицу IMEI?

Comment: Ну логично, `ICollection<ImeiList>` не содержит свойства `IMEI`, поэтому ничего не выводится. В каком виде вы хотите вывести эту коллекцию в одной ячейке таблицы?

Comment: "Наименование (производитель)", "Модель", "IMEI". Чтобы все возможные варианты выводились.

Comment: И это всё внутри одной ячейки? Можете эскиз нарисовать, как это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Это три столбца и три разные ячейки.

Comment: Ок, у вас в одном экземпляре `CDevice` содержится одно наименование, одна модель и целая куча IMEI, как вы хотите их вывести в одной ячейке таблицы?

Comment: Я понимаю. Мне нужно вывести экземпляры со всеми возможными пересекающимися комбинациями. Например, если у одного устройства 2 IMEI, то в таблицу нужно вывести два экземпляра. И наоборот, если у одного IMEI - два устройства, тоже два экземпляра.

Comment: Еще раз повторюсь. По запросу, если смотреть через PROFILER, SQL-запрос выполняется правильный и выводятся все необходимые результаты. Они же есть и в коллекции, если смотреть через точку останова, но почему-то добраться до них я не могу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам придется в VM использовать плоские экземпляры, а при работе с БД преобразовывать их в иерархические.

Напишите такой VM-класс (не забудьте про имплементацию INPC если она нужна):

```
public class DeviceVM
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ImeiId { get; set; }
    public long Imei { get; set; }
}
```

В главной VM храните коллекцию именно `DeviceVM` и привязку в XAML выполняйте к ней.

Преобразование коллекции `CDevice` в коллекцию `DeviceVM` будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
DeviceVMCollection =
    CDeviceCollection
        .SelectMany(d => d.ImeiList.Select(i =>
            new DeviceVM
            {
                DeviceId = d.Id,
                Model = d.Model,
                Title = d.Title,
                ImeiId = i.Id,
                Imei = i.IMEI
            }));
```