# List<T> с DisplayName в DataTable

Tags: c#, ооп, list, datatable

Добрый день. 
Имеется следующий код, который хорошо копирует данные из List c DisplayName в DataTable:

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        var table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.DisplayName != null)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(prop.DisplayName, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType)
                    ?? prop.PropertyType);
            }
        }
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Но я не могу додумать, как этот код дописать, если у меня следующая структура списка:

```
    public class Man
{
    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    [DisplayName("Возраст")]
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public bool IsJob { get; set; }

}
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Man> man = new List<Man>();
    }
}
```

Т.е. мне необходимо дописать мой расширяющий метод так, чтобы  в  таблицу попали данные и с класса Info с DisplayName. Чтобы DataTable имел колонки: "Имя", "Фамилия" и "Возраст".  Внутри не будет списков и прочего. Именно такая структура будет. Списков с DisplayName не будет.

Comment: Вам придется преобразовать коллекцию иерархических структур в коллекцию плоских, примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779080/218063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе вам уже подсказали в комментариях под вашим вопросом, но все же.

через ваш вариант.

```
public class ManVM
{   
    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Фамилия")]
    public string Family { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Возвраст")]
    public string Age { get; set; }
}

public static class Hi
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        var table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.DisplayName != null)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(prop.DisplayName, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            }
        }
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                if (prop.DisplayName != null)
                {
                    row[prop.DisplayName] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value; //тут была ошибка у вас?
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Man> mans = new List<Man>();
        mans.Add(new Man()
        {
            Family = "st",
            Name = "Yr",
            Info = new Info()
            {
                Age = "12",
                IsJob = true
            }
        });
        mans.Add(new Man()
        {
            Family = "zx",
            Name = "hjgh",
            Info = new Info()
            {
                Age = "13",
                IsJob = true
            }
        });
        mans.Add(new Man()
        {
            Family = "asd",
            Name = "saffg",
            Info = new Info()
            {
                Age = "13",
                IsJob = true
            }
        });

        List<ManVM> mansVm = new List<ManVM>();
        foreach (var item in mans)
        {
            mansVm.Add(new ManVM()
            {
                Age = item.Info.Age,
                Family = item.Family,
                Name = item.Name
            });
        }

        var table = Hi.ToDataTable<ManVM>(mansVm);
}
```

через сериализацию

```
public class ManVM
{
    [JsonProperty("Имя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Фамилия")]
    public string Family { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Возвраст")]
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

все тоже самое, только вместо

```
        var table = Hi.ToDataTable<ManVM>(mansVm);
```

вставить это

```
        var json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mansVm);
        var datatable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
```

для второго варианта нужно будет подключить библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json.